# Rust Collect Hashmap from Iterator of Pairs

Tags: rust, hashmap, iterator, tuples

We have a HashMap, over which we iterate and map to replace the values, but are running into an issue collecting that back to a new HashMap with different value type.

```
value of type `std::collections::HashMap<std::string::String, std::string::String>`
cannot be built from `std::iter::Iterator<Item=(&std::string::String, std::string::String)>`
```

What we are doing essentially boils down to this:

```
let old: HashMap<String, Value> = some_origin();
let new: HashMap<String, String> = old.iter().map(|(key, value)| {
  return (key, some_conversion(value));
}).collect();
```

The same iterator type is also returned (and not collectable), if one zips two iterators, e.g. in this case zipping key, and the map that only returns the converted value.

```
new = old.keys().into_iter().zip(old.iter().map(|(key, value)| some_conversion(value)).collect();
```

Comment: try `key.clone()`, [mcve] would be better

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The issue is that `iter()` ([docs](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/collections/struct.HashMap.html#method.iter)) returns a 'non-consuming' iterator which hands out references to the underlying values ([1]). The new `HashMap` cannot be constructed using references (`&String`), it needs values (`String`).

In your example, `some_conversion` seems to return a new `String` for the value part, so applying `.clone()` to the key would do the trick:

```rust
let old: HashMap<String, Value> = some_origin();
let new: HashMap<String, String> = old.iter().map(|(key, value)| {
  return (key.clone(), some_conversion(value));
  //         ^---- .clone() call inserted
}).collect();
```

[Here](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=b682479501eff8f68a632e992620e909) is a link to a full example on the rust playground.

Looking at the error message from the compiler [2], this is indeed quite hard to figure out. I think what most helps with this is to build up an intuition around references and ownership in Rust to understand when references are OK and when an owned value is needed.

While I'd recommend reading the sections on references and ownership in the Rust Book and even more Programming Rust, the gist is as follows:

1. Usually, values in Rust have exactly one owner (exceptions are explicit shared ownership pointers, such as `Rc`).
2. When a value is passed 'by value' it is moved to the new location. This invalidates the original owner of the value.
3. There can be multiple shared references to a value, but while any shared reference exists, the value is immutable (no mutable references can exist or be created, so it cannot be modified or moved).
4. We cannot move a value out of a shared reference (this would invalidate the original owner, which is immutable while a shared reference exists).
5. Usually, Rust doesn't automatically copy (in Rust parlance "clone") values, even if it could. Instead it takes ownership of values. (The exception are "`Copy`" types which are cheap to copy, such as `i32`).
6. (Not relevant here) There can also be a single mutable reference to a value. While this mutable reference exits no shared references can be created.

How does this help?

- Who owns the keys in the hash map? The hash map does (rule 1)!
- But how do we get a new key-value pair into the hash map? The values are moved into the hash map (rule 2).
- But we can't move out of a shared reference ... (rule 3 + rule 4)
- And Rust doesn't want to clone the value unless we tell it to do so (rule 5)
- ... so we have to clone it ourselves.

I hope this gives some intuition (again I would really recommend Programming Rust on this). In general, if you do something with a value, you either take ownership over it, or you get a reference. If you take ownership, the original variable that had ownership can no longer be used. If you get a reference, you can't hand ownership to somebody else (without cloning). And Rust doesn't clone for you.

[1]: The docs call this "An iterator visiting all key-value pairs in arbitrary order. The iterator element type is (&'a K, &'a V)." Ignoring the `'a` lifetime parameters, you can see that the element type is `(&K, &V)`.

[2]:

```
13 |         .collect();
   |          ^^^^^^^ value of type `std::collections::HashMap<std::string::String, std::string::String>` cannot be built from `std::iter::Iterator<Item=(&std::string::String, std::string::String)>`
   |
   = help: the trait `std::iter::FromIterator<(&std::string::String, std::string::String)>` is not implemented for `std::collections::HashMap<std::string::String, std::string::String>`
```

Comment: Seems to indeed remove the compiler error. Wouldn't have ever guessed that from the error message complaining about the iterator to hashmap conversion though.

Comment: Yeah, I agree that this is hard to figure out. I was actually going to post an edit that tried to show how to read the error message from the compiler, but then I had to admit that it is actually not that easy to infer from the error. What helps is a good understanding of ownership and references, that can give an intuition when references are OK and when not.

Comment: @autarchprinceps: I attempted an explanation on the intuition behind this - HTH.

Comment: I think you can also avoid the clone if you don't want the old map any more and use `into_iter()` instead.

Answer (score 3):

If you don't need the old map any more you can just use `into_iter`.

```
let new: HashMap<String, String> = old.into_iter().map(|(key, value)| {
   return (key, some_conversion(value));
}).collect();
```

You can see a working version [here](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=1778064dd971ad1b066234c9541d00e1)